# Citrix Xen Center to Manage XEN 4.1 running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: virtualization, xen, citrix

I have been using virt manager to manage XEN and it crashes often so i moved to Citrix Xencenter but i can not make it work.

Details:
using XEN 4.1 running on ubuntu 12.04

citrix XenCenter Installed on windows XP

No firewall or network issue exist as i can ping XEN running on ubuntu 12.04.

when i try to add server its showing

> Unable to Connect to server 'ip-address' connection was refused.Check
>   that XENServer is configured correctly on 'ip-address' and try again

Should i need to enable anything in XEN Configuration file to allow accessing XEN from citrix XENCenter..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix Xen is a complete operating system on it's own running from a modified CentOS machine. If you are not running Citrix Xen on your server, then you will not be able to connect to it with XenCenter.

You can not use XenCenter with a default Xen, your OS *has* to be XenServer.

You can get it over here: http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_2304908.asp

**Edit**

For those who are *still* asking why they can't manage their Xen with XenCenter:

XenCenter is built to manage Citrix XenServer. Asking why your default Xen can not be managed by XenCenter is like asking "Why can't I manage Xen with my vsphere client?". Citrix XenCenter is ***not*** an add-on for Xen it is the

### ***management panel for Citrix XenServer***

which is a

## ***standalone operating system***

!

#### This means you can't install or use it with a non-Citrix XenServer version of Xen.

Comment: in that case Is there any alternative for Virtmanager?
i tried Openxen manager but same is the result..Can u help for an alternative that works as like citrix xencenter

Comment: There won't be anything out there that will run as good as Citrix XenCenter for your case. All the features depend on XenServer. You should try to find out why virtmanager keeps crashing.

Comment: so in my case i can not use XenCenter :(

Comment: Unless you re-install your system and migrate the current VM's to Citrix Xen, then no.

Comment: Thanx alot Lucas kauffman... Thank you very much...

Comment: Currently i share Hosts Public IP with VM for assigning each VM public IP using bridge.Will i be able to do this,when i use bare metal hypervisor.Since our Host is a dedicated machine from a hosting provider.

Comment: I don't think that's a free feature, you will need to test it first

Comment: Any ideas why it does not work? Does Citrix XEN Center has to be installed on the Dom0 or does it use the xend-API?

Comment: Yes, as I said, XenCenter is built to manage Citrix XenServer, your question would is about the same as asking, "Why can't I manage Xen with my vsphere client?". Citrix XenCenter is not an add-on for Xen it is an entire Operating system!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer is mostly incorrect.

Citrix XenCenter connects to Xenserver through the XAPI toolstack. Therefore, any instance of Xen that uses the XAPI toolstack can be managed through Citrix XenCenter.

I've managed Citrix Xenserver, Xen Cloud Platform, and Xen on Ubuntu 12.04 with Citrix XenCenter.

Citrix XenServer and Xen Cloud Platform use the XAPI toolstack by default. When using Xen with Ubuntu 12.04, you will need to switch from the xm (or xl) toolstack to the XAPI toolstack. The following link should give you a pretty good idea of how to do so:

http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/06/28/installing-xcp-xapi-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts/

**EDIT in response to comment:**

The Xen Cloud Platform is a completely open source version of XenServer. It's a CentOS based distribution with some packages that provide functionality similar to what XenServer's capabilities. One of these packages is the XAPI package. This provides the XAPI toolstack which allows you to use XenCenter to manage the server.

What the blog mentions is installing the `xcp-xapi` package in Ubuntu to provide the XAPI toolstack.

Comment: Doesn't that blog mentioning about installing Xen Cloud Platform(XCP)?Which uses xen hypervisor with xapi api?

Answer (score 2):

If i'm not mistaken, XenCenter actually communicates with xapi, not xen.  Xapi controls xen.  XenServer is basically just CentOS + xen + xapi + some kind of license server.  If you look around on xen.org, you can find XCP, which is the open source version of XenServer, i.e. CentOS + xen + xapi.  It is entirely controllable with XenCenter, I happen to be doing just that.

I see no real reason why you couldn't control your xen machine with XenCenter, as long as you had xapi in place for XenCenter to talk to, and (maybe) whatever repository scheme is set up in XCP/XenServer.  It would probably be a lot of work, but shouldn't be impossible.

- this *may* solve the problem nicely: [XCP in Ubuntu](http://xen.org/news/2012/05_xcp_in_ubuntu_server_12_04_LTS.html)
- how to use XenCenter to manage XCP: [Xen Wiki](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Using_XenCenter_to_manage_XCP)

I had 2 more links, but apparently, i'm not popular enough to post them. :)